# Sintaxis JQPL Filter list

Tags: java, jpql

i need some help.

I have this two tables

```
public class Publication implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPublication")
    private Integer idPublication;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "publication")
    private List<Question> questionList;

    ....
}
```

Tabla Question

```
public class Question implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idQuestion")
    private Integer idQuestion;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 500)
    @Column(name = "pregunta")
    private String question;

    @JoinColumn(name = "publication", referencedColumnName = "idPublication")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Publication publication;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean activo;

    ....
}
```

I need to get the publications with the questions who has active = true.
Example: i have publication A and publication B, where A has 5 questions with 2 active and B has 6 questions with 5 active.

I try to do "Select p from Publication p, Question que where p.idPublication = que.publication.idPublication and que.activo = 1" but it returns the publication with all their questions...

I cant finde a solution to this

please helps

Greets

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do *exactly* what you want because the entities returned from a JPQL query reflect what is in the database (or persistence context). In other words, when you select an entity from a JPQL query, you're getting the entire entity -- you can't filter its relationships because then the entity wouldn't reflect whats in the database anymore.

In your example, you are essentially selecting `Publication`s that have at least 1 active `Question`.

To solve your problem, you could build a `Map` of `Publication` to active `Question`s. Something like this:

```
TypedQuery<Question> query = 
  em.createQuery("select q from Question q where q.activo = true", Question.class);
List<Question> activeQuestions = query.getResultList();

Map<Publication, List<Question>> publicationToActiveQuestions = new HashMap<>();
for (Question q : activeQuestions)
{
  List<Question> publicationQuestions = publicationToActiveQuestions.get(q.getPublication());
  if (publicationQuestions == null)
  {
    publicationQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    publicationToActiveQuestions.put(q.getPublication(), publicationQuestions);
  }
  publicationQuestions.add(q);
}
```